# Shell script task in azuredevops is not working for resource existence check in Jfrog

Tags: shell, azure-devops, artifactory, azure-devops-rest-api, jfrog-cli

I have a azuredevops Script task to check existence of artifactory group and action according to the result. I am using jfrog api calls to check the existence and which will not get a common output parameter to check the existence,eg: for non-existence it will be 404 , but for existence the it will show the details not response as 200.

```
stages:
  - ${{ each project in parameters.projectList }}:  
    - stage: Group_Creation_${{ project.projectname }}
      displayName: 'Group cration for the ${{ project.projectname }}'
      variables:
          - group: jfrog-config
      pool: 
        name: az-dev
      jobs:
        - job: GroupExistanceCheck

          - script: |
               echo "Checking if Groups already exists..."
               exists_grp=$(curl -u '$(jfuser):$(jfpass)' -X GET "$(jfurl)/api/security/groups/${{ project.projectname }}-developers" | jq .name)
               if [[ "$exists_grp" == ${{ project.projectname }}-developers ]] ; then
                 echo "${{ project.projectname }}-developers is existing and nothing to do"
               fi  
               if [[ "$exists_grp" = null ]]; then
                 echo "${{ project.projectname }}-developers is NOT existing and will be creatiing now"
                 /azp/_work/_tool/jf/2.25.5/x64/jf rt group-create ${{ project.projectname }}-developers --url $(jfurl) --user $(jfuser) --password $(jfpass)
               fi
            displayName: 'check Developer Group Existance & create if not existing'
```

Here even though the groups are existing , its not printing and taking action accordingly just skipping the part

Comment: Does this command work when run outside of this script? Does your `${jfurl}` include `/artifactory`? Note that "From Artifactory release 7.49.3, these APIs are being replaced by the new SECURITY APIs available in the JFrog Platform." You should move to https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Platform+REST+API#JFrogPlatformRESTAPI-GetGroupDetails

Comment: Yes.. command is working when we are executing from terminal, and our artifactory version is 7.41.4

Comment: So something in the script's env is wrong. Try maybe adding an `env` command and maybe an `sh -x`. Also, remove the `jq` and observe the output.